# How to debug spamassassin running via Plesk 8.4

Tags: email, spamassassin

I am helping someone with their Plesk (8.4) based Linux server, which runs qmail and spamassassin.

Spam Filter is configured via the control panel and seems to be running on the server.

The following is output whenever the config is changed:

```
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15677]: spamd: server hit by SIGHUP, restarting 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15677]: spamd: child 15678 killed successfully 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15677]: spamd: child 15679 killed successfully 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15677]: logger: removing stderr method 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: rules: meta test DIGEST_MULTIPLE has undefined dependency 'DCC_CHECK' 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: spamd: server started on UNIX domain socket /tmp/spamd_full.sock (running version 3.1.9) 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: spamd: server pid: 15681 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 15682 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 15683 
Feb 17 13:24:44 ip-72-167-112-76 spamd[15681]: prefork: child states: II
```

But mail seems to not being checked - in particular blacklisted items are not marked - come through as ok.

If I run spamassassin on the command line, it works ok, considering emails blacklisted addresses as spam.

```
spamassassin -t -D < /tmp/spam
```

I don't see any errors/messages in the /var/log/messages or /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog

Have found a vague reference to something similar [here](http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-82141.html) - perhaps we need to update spamassassin.

And also a [link](http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-83054.html) saying to run mchk, but not sure how destructive that would be...

Any tips on how to debug this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the mchk process and that fixed the problem.